# ExtJS 4 using store filter with combobox and gridPanel - filtered data not shown

Tags: ajax, extjs

I'm having really hard time to understand or maybe more correct will be to say - to use filters on any of my store and loading the info in the grid. I have a more complex task but in order to understand how things work I decided to use as most simple example as I could just to see how things happen and then to add more logic so I can grind my knowledge. However still I don't get any encouraging results so I'm again asking for help.

I have a gridPanel in my model which use his own store, in this case :

> "RecordsListStore"

And I have

> xtype: combo;

which looks like this:

```
            xtype: 'combo',
            id: 'records_list_author_id',
            emptyText: 'Филтриране по автор',
            editable: false,
            store: 'Users',
            displayField: 'firstname',
            valueField: 'id',
            lastQuery: '',
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        queryMode: 'remote',
                        typeAhead: false,
            width: 200,
            listeners: {
                          select: this._filterRecords
                   }
```

Which uses it's own store to load data in the combobox which could be selected from the user.

The thirs part, the select function is:

```
_filterRecords: function()
    {
        var recStore =  Ext.getStore('FilterRecordsByAuthor');
        var a = Ext.getCmp('records_list_author_id').getValue( );
        var rec = Ext.getStore('FilterRecordsByForm').getAt(a);
        recStore.filters.clear();
            //recStore.load();
        recStore.filter([{
            "property":'form_id',
            "value": 1
                   }]);
        console.log(recStore.load());
    },
```

Here comes a third store which I think to use for fetching the the filtered data. The problem is that the console log shows that I send the filters but everytime I get empty result. But if everything works as I thought it should there must me some info, so there's mistake or something missing, but I can't figure out what should be done.

Comment: So using this  `_filterRecords: function()
 {
  var a = Ext.getCmp('records_list_author_id').getValue( );
  var rec = Ext.getStore('RecordsListStore');
  rec.filters.clear();
  rec.filter([{
    "property":'author_id',
    "value": a
   }]);
  console.log(a);
 }`,I get things working now the grid is loaded with the info, I just needed to add $data['filter'] in my SQL query but now I want to relod the store without filters any ideas?I try this `handler: function() {
      var rec = Ext.getStore('RecordsListStore');

      rec.load();
     }` but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getValue()` of combobox will give you value from the combobox not index in the store. So after you got this value you need to actually look record up with something like `store.findExact('some_field', value)` and only after that `getAt()` with the index you got.

Comment: Hmm, maybe my questions are not very explanational, but I'm still struggling with ExtJS. Anyways with `getValue()` from the combo I get the actual id of the selected element, which after that I use to create my SQL query.For example - SELECT...WHERE author_id = and here come the value from getValue().And it works fine in terms of r server side filtering. And I find out a way to reload the full grid, just calling `clearFilter();` before `load()` and this also works.

Comment: Now along with the grid reset I need to return the `emptyText` value of the combobox, but I guess it's something similar to getting the full store info. Thanks for the support sha! <3 !!!

Comment: Reseting the combobox empty value occurs to be a simple tasks but since I don't find nothing easy in ExtJS 4 I'll post how I did it: `var cBox1 = Ext.getCmp('records_list_form_id');
 var cBox2 = Ext.getCmp('records_list_author_id');
 cBox1.reset();
 cBox2.reset();`